# Digit Sum for Base 2 Alternate Definition

Tags: elementary-number-theory, summation, number-systems

I was looking at the [digit sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digit_sum) definition, but I also saw a simpler version that can be used for binary numbers. I'm trying to figure out and understand how the generic formula for any base can be simplified into this version that works for base 2 ([A000120](https://oeis.org/A000120)). Why are they compatible?

Digit Sum Definition for base b:

$$F_b(n)=\sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor\log_b{n}\rfloor}\frac{n \bmod{b^{i+1}} - n \bmod b^i}{b^i}$$

Digit Sum Definition for base 2:

$$F_2(n)=n - \sum_{i=1}^{\lfloor\log_2{n}\rfloor}\bigg\lfloor\frac{n}{2^i}\bigg\rfloor$$

Comment: I recommend actually computing the binary digit sum of several smallish numbers (say 2-digit numbers) by hand with each formula. That will be the best thing to develop an understanding of the formulas.

Comment: The key point is that the binary representation of $2^j - 1$ comprises $(j-1)$ $1$s. This lets you show by induction that as you increment the number of non-zero bits in a number, the second formula for $F_2(n)$ increments too, because the least significant bit, at bit position $j$ say, contributes $2^j - 1$ to the sum. I can give a more detailed answer if you like, but not today.

Comment: @RobArthan Just out of curiosity, what programming language would you recommend as a *starter* language for someone who has never programmed before?  Python?

Comment: @user2661923: yours is a strange question for an MSE comment that has nothing directly to do with programming. I probably would say Python, but I don't teach programming or work much with junior programmers, so my opinions aren't worth much.

Comment: @RobArthan Noticed your programming background.  I have received contradictory responses on whether Python should be one's 1st programming language.  As a professional programmer who is totally ignorant of Python, I'm not qualified to have an opinion.  Issue arises periodically on MathSE, and I'm unsure which language to recommend.

Comment: @RobArthan yes, I'd love a detailed explanation, thanks.